# Generate an associative array from command output

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I am writing a zsh completion function to complete IDs from a database. There is a program `listnotes` which outputs a list like this:

```
bf848bf6-63d2-474b-a2c0-e7e3c4865ce8   Note Title
aba21e55-22c6-4c50-8bf6-bf3b337468e2   Another one
09ead915-bf2d-449d-a943-ff589e79794a   yet another "one"
...
```

How do I generate an associative array `note_ids` from the output of the `listnotes` command such that I get an associative array like this?

```
( bf848bf6-63d2-474b-a2c0-e7e3c4865ce8 "Note Title" aba21e55-22c6-4c50-8bf6-bf3b337468e2 "Another one" 09ead915-bf2d-449d-a943-ff589e79794a "yet another \"one\"" )
```

Note that there may be whitespace in the keys. I tried to generate something with `sed`:

```
note_ids=($(listnotes | sed 's/^\(.*\)   \(.*\)$/\1 "\2"/'))
```

but quoting strings like this doesn’t seem to work, and double quotes in the title make it even more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
typeset -A note_ids
for line in ${(f)"$(listnotes)"}; do
    note_ids+=(${line%% *} ${line#*   })
done
```

- `${(f)PARAM}`: split the result of the expansion of `$PARAM` at newlines
- `"$(listnotes)"`: put the output of `listnotes` verbatim into the expansion.
- `for line in LIST`: iterate over the items in `LIST` as split by `${(f)…}`.
- `note_ids+=(key value)`: add key-value pair to an the associative array `note_ids`
- `${line%% *}`: cut the largest portion matching `" *"` (a space followed by anything) from the end of the expansion of `line`. So remove everying after including the first space, leaving only the key.
- `${line#*   }`: cut the smallest portion matching `"*    "` (anything followed by three spaces) from the beginning of the expansion of `$line`. So remove the key and the three spaces used as separator.

Instead of using the parameter expansion flag `(f)` you could also read the output of `listnotes` line by line with `read`:

```
listnotes | while read; do 
    note_ids+=(${REPLY%% *} ${REPLY#*   })
done
```

Unless specified otherwise `read` puts the read values into the `REPLY` parameter.

Comment: `read key value <<< $line; note_id[$key]=$value` should also work. That's probably a little clearer to read.